# How consume Kafka message from different server using spring boot microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

We have an application that sends the message let say "Hello world" from ***one spring boot*** server let say the server port number is 8080 and we need to send this message to the other server using ***Kafka*** which at the port number 8090. How to consume those services on 8090 port server. Can you please suggest what I did wrong on this

*Producer running on 8080 port*

```
package com.xerox.pps.Kafka.services;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class KafkaProducer {

private Source mySource;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaProducer.class);

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    String kafkaTopic = "java_in_use_topic";


    public void send(String message) {
        logger.info(String.format("#### -> Producing message -> %s", message));
        kafkaTemplate.send(kafkaTopic, message);
    }
    @KafkaListener(topics = "hello_world_topic1", groupId = "java_in_use_topic-0")
    public void consume(String message) throws IOException {
        logger.info(String.format("#### ->Recived message -> %s", message));
    }


}
```

*Consumer running on 8090*

```
package com.xerox.pps.Kafka.services;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Sink;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class KafkaConsumer {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumer.class);

    @Autowired private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;



    @KafkaListener(topics = "java_in_use_topic", groupId = "java_in_use_topic-0")
    @StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT)

    public void consume(String message) throws IOException {
          logger.info(String.format("#### -> Consumed message -> %s", message));
          kafkaTemplate.send("hello_world_topic1", message+" Response"); 
    }

}
```

*** application.properties file***

```
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer


#spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

spring.cloud.stream.default-binder=kafka
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9092
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=java_in_use_topic-0
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.binder=kafka
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=test
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type=text/plain
```

Comment: What are the logs you are seeing? Are you seeing the "#### -> Producing message -> " log in the producer but not the "#### -> Consumed message -> " in the consumer?

Comment: Also assume that the producer and consumer have their own application.properties files?

Comment: @JosephRajeevMotha yes I am seeing  Producing message -> " log in the producer but not the "#### -> Consumed message -> " in the consumer

Comment: @JosephRajeevMotha yes producer and consumer have individual application.properties file like above

Comment: Have you tried a different consumer? I would suggest firing up kafka-console-consumer on the CLI and see if it can receive the messages.